# Concurrency not handled in Eclipse Link when using Spring JpaTransactionManager

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink, multi-tenant

We are using Multi Tenant Transaction manager as described in above post dated Registered: November 2014. we are using Spring Data and also we are identifying tenant based on user ID and password, i.e we do not know the tenant first in hand. the application is working fine. We are using spring security with basic authentication. and the application is exposed through Rest API.

The problem occurs when concurrent different tenants use the Transaction manager at the same time. we use TenantResolver class to find the tenant

We have other 2 messaging flow which has around 40 messages and 10 messages per min which uses the connection manager to find the tenant and perform transactions based on that.

The logs here:

> MultiTenantJpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction()->
>   ACTUAL_TENANT : vce 07:51:05,720 INFO
>   [xxx.integration.jms.VehicleRepositoryListener]
>   (vrMessageListenerContainer-1) []
>   VehicleRepositoryListener.onMessage()--> Process successfully
>   completed in VehicleRepositoryListener 07:51:05,768 ERROR
>   [xxx.integration.services.utils.TenantUtils]
>   (vrMessageListenerContainer-1) [] TenantUtils.setTenantByProductClass
>   -> Error in setting the Tenant org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Exception
>   [EclipseLink-28013] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>   Exception Description: Unable to deploy PersistenceUnit [default] in
>   invalid state [DeployFailed]. Internal Exception:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>   Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [default] failed.
>   Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit. Internal Exception:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28009]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>   Exception Description: Attempted to redeploy a session named
>   /file:/opt/jboss64/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/ejb3/main/timers/_default
>   without closing it.; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28013]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>   Exception Description: Unable to deploy PersistenceUnit [default] in
>   invalid state [DeployFailed]. Internal Exception:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>   Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [default] failed.
>   Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit. Internal Exception:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28009]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>   Exception Description: Attempted to redeploy a session named
>   /file:/opt/jboss64/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/ejb3/main/timers/_default
>   without closing it. 07:51:05,774 INFO
>   [xxxintegration.services.XXXUpdateRequestProcessServiceImpl]
>   (xxxMessageListenerContainer-1) [] Returning from
>   XXXUpdateRequestProcessServiceImpl.login() 07:51:05,775 INFO
>   [xxx.integration.services.XXXUpdateRequestProcessServiceImpl]
>   (xxxMessageListenerContainer-1) []
>   XXXUpdateRequestProcessServiceImpl.getUpdateTechToolResponseDTOs()->
>   Token in Service :b3b00ab6-5c36-45af-8ec2-0b6f1710e888 07:51:05,777
>   INFO [xxx.integration.services.VehicleRepositoryService]
>   (vrMessageListenerContainer-1) []
>   VehicleRepositoryService.parseVehicleRepositoryUpdate()-> Tenant is
>   null 07:51:05,780 INFO [xxx.integration.jms.VehicleRepositoryListener]
>   (vrMessageListenerContainer-1) []
>   VehicleRepositoryListener.onMessage()--> Process successfully
>   completed in VehicleRepositoryListener 07:51:06,138 INFO
>   [xxx.application.VehicleActivationService] (http-/0.0.0.0:16780-71) []
>   Inside VehicleActivationService.checkActivation() 07:51:06,141 INFO
>   [xxx.application.VehicleActivationService] (http-/0.0.0.0:16780-71) []
>   Inside VehicleActivationService.getTenant() 07:51:06,145 ERROR
>   [xxx.integration.rest.UpdateTechTool] (http-/0.0.0.0:16780-71) []
>   Exception in check activation method : Could not open JPA
>   EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28013]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>   Exception Description: Unable to deploy PersistenceUnit [default] in
>   invalid state [DeployFailed]. Internal Exception:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>   Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [default] failed.
>   Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit. Internal Exception:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28009]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>   Exception Description: Attempted to redeploy a session named
>   /file:/opt/jboss64/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/ejb3/main/timers/_default
>   without closing it. 07:51:06,148 INFO
>   [xxx.application.XXXUpdateTechToolDTOService] (http-/0.0.0.0:16780-71)
>   [] Inside UpdateTechToolDTOService.update() 07:51:06,154 ERROR
>   [xxx.application.XXXUpdateTechToolDTOService] (http-/0.0.0.0:16780-71)
>   [] XXXUpdateTechToolDTOService.update() -> EXCEPTION while calling
>   update :java.lang.NullPointerException 07:51:06,166 INFO
>   [xxx.integration.services.UpdateRequestProcessServiceImpl]
>   (MessageListenerContainer-1) [] Inside
>   UpdateRequestProcessServiceImpl.createResponse() 07:51:06,883 INFO
>   [stdout] (Finalizer) [] [EL Info]: connection: 2017-04-17
>   07:51:06.882--ServerSession(1485077057)--/file:/opt/jboss64/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/ejb3/main/timers/_default
>   logout successful 07:51:06,885 INF

Any help or way to handle concurrent issues.

Similar to :
[EclipseLink - Error: Attempted to redeploy a session without closing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241866/eclipselink-error-attempted-to-redeploy-a-session-without-closing-it/44151847?noredirect=1#comment75322124_44151847)

The MultiTenantJpaTransactionManager  class used is:

public class MultiTenantJpaTransactionManager extends JpaTransactionManager {

```
TenantResolver<Tenant> tenantResolver; 
SchemaProvider schemaProvider; 
@Autowired
public void setTenantResolver(TenantResolver<Tenant> tenantResolver) {
    this.tenantResolver = tenantResolver;
}

@Autowired(required = false)
public void setSchemaProvider(SchemaProvider schemaProvider) {
    this.schemaProvider = schemaProvider;
}

@Override
protected synchronized javax.persistence.EntityManager createEntityManagerForTransaction() {
    boolean refreshed = false;
    EntityManager em = super.createEntityManagerForTransaction();
    try {
        LOGGER.info("Entering createEntityManagerforTransaction()");
        if (schemaProvider != null) {
            TenantSessionCustomizer.setSchemaName(schemaProvider.getSchema());
        }
        ServerSession ss = ((EntityManagerImpl) em.getDelegate()).getServerSession();
        Map sessionProp = ss.getProperties();
        String actualTenant = (String) sessionProp.get(PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT);
        LOGGER.info("MultiTenantJpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction()-> ACTUAL_TENANT : " + actualTenant);

        if (tenantResolver != null && tenantResolver.getCurrentTenant() != null) {
            LOGGER.info("MultiTenantJpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction()-> CURRENT_TENANT : " + tenantResolver.getCurrentTenant());
            if ((actualTenant == null) || (actualTenant != null && !actualTenant.equals(tenantResolver.getCurrentTenant().getHandle()))) {
                sessionProp.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT, tenantResolver.getCurrentTenant().getHandle());
                sessionProp.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.SESSION_CUSTOMIZER, TenantSessionCustomizer.class.getName());
                MetadataRefreshListener mrl = ((EntityManagerImpl) em.getDelegate()).getServerSession().getRefreshMetadataListener();
                if (mrl != null) {
                    Map<String, Object> prop = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    mrl.triggerMetadataRefresh(prop);
                    refreshed = true;
                    LOGGER.info("createEntityManagerforTransaction()---->Metadata refreshed");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("MultiTenantJpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction()-> Exception while creating EntityManagerForTransaction " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return refreshed ? super.createEntityManagerForTransaction() : em;
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like Spring is attempting to redeploy the EMF with new credentials while an old one is still in use, but giving both the same session name.  You'll need to tag this as a Spring question as I don't know the Spring internals, but it needs to provide a unique session name to allow for different tenant credentials to be used and kept separate.

Comment: Hi Chris, Do you have any proper example where you use seperate credentials without defining persistance xml and for single table multi tenancy, aslo we are using spring 4.x  which is annotation driven. We determine the tenent using spring data using the same connection based of user id and password in rest api based calls.

Comment: Single table multitenancy doesn't needed seperate credentials - see https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/multitenancy002.htm  Why are you using different credentials?  I'm not sure how this is setup in Spring, but they need to be configured as different persistence units for each set of credentials (if required).

Comment: We are not using separate credentials as well not using persistence.xml or different PU.

Comment: Is this a know issue in EL or Spring? Or we have any alternative way of doing it?

Comment: You are likely making some incorrect assumptions in your createEntityManagerForTransaction method.  The server session you are obtaining is the shared session underneath all EntityManagerFactories  - you are setting something to be used on all threads, and then seem to be calling triggerMetadataRefresh on it - presumably to have any a new EMF get created underneath the covers so that any new EntityManagers use these settings.  You might want to revisit what exactly you are trying to set, as there is likely a better way by just passing the properties to the emf.getEntityManager method.

Comment: I cannot use emf.getEntityManager method as we are extending JPATransaction Manager and overriding createEntityManagerForTransaction as we are using PersistanceContext and Transactional. Can we still use it?

Comment: You are creating an entirely new persistence unit with 'default' settings so that every EntityManager obtained from it uses the default tenant when it isn't defined.  This causes the entire persistence unit to be reloaded while every other thread waits.  Instead, you need to look at what the super.createEntityManagerForTransaction() does and not rely on it then to give you the entityManager.  The settings/properties you are using to 'refresh' the factory should be passed to the EntityManager when it is created, allowing you to use the same EntityManagerFactory and obtain an EM per tenant

Comment: The super.createEntityManagerForTransaction() is used for getting the current Tenant from the DB,  when you say properties set ot refresh the EM where should the sessionProp be set in the code (which line).

Comment: Is checking the current tenant a necessary if EM is per tenant? And is it necessary to refresh the EM if the tenants do not match?

Comment: super.createEntityManagerForTransaction() is getting you an EntityManager, so I'm not sure what it or your code is really for.  The code you've shown calls tenantResolver.getCurrentTenant() to get the current tenant - you need to make this call, and pass the result into the EMF.getEntityManager method as a property any time you need an EntityManager.  The EntityManager provided then is only for the current tenant operation - you should not be holding onto EntityManagers for extended periods anyway. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Multitenant#Simple_Example

Comment: We are getting the Issue when 2 different tenants come together, that actual tenant is T1 and current tenant is T2.                                                                We are getting the Issue  "Exception Description: Attempted to redeploy a session named file:/opt/jboss64/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-6.4.5.CP/org/jboss/as/ejb3/main/timers/_default without closing it."                                                                                 
 when  LOGGER.info("createEntityManagerforTransaction()---->Metadata refreshed");  metadata is refereshed.

Comment: All the Entity metadata is being defaulted in the logs.

Comment: Is there an alternate way for the code: MetadataRefreshListener mrl = ((EntityManagerImpl) em.getDelegate()).getServerSession().getRefreshMetadataListener();  if (mrl != null) {Map<String, Object> prop = new HashMap<String, Object>(); mrl.triggerMetadataRefresh(prop);refreshed = true; }}}

Comment: I cannot help as I have no idea why you are using MetadataRefresh logic. This was designed for dynamic entities, allowing you to change mappings on the fly, not for multi tenancy. To chance tenant options, you only need to pass in the new parameters when obtaining the EntityManager or EntityManagerFactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class MultiTenantJpaTransactionManager extends JpaTransactionManager {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultiTenantJpaTransactionManager.class);

```
TenantResolver<Tenant> tenantResolver; 
SchemaProvider schemaProvider;

@Autowired
public void setTenantResolver(TenantResolver<Tenant> tenantResolver) {
    this.tenantResolver = tenantResolver;
}

@Autowired(required = false)
public void setSchemaProvider(SchemaProvider schemaProvider) {
    this.schemaProvider = schemaProvider;
}

@Override
protected synchronized javax.persistence.EntityManager createEntityManagerForTransaction() {
    boolean refreshed = false;
    EntityManagerFactory emf = getEntityManagerFactory();
    EntityManager em = super.createEntityManagerForTransaction();
    try {
        LOGGER.info("Entering createEntityManagerforTransaction()");
        if (schemaProvider != null) {
            TenantSessionCustomizer.setSchemaName(schemaProvider.getSchema());
        }
        ServerSession ss = ((EntityManagerImpl) em.getDelegate()).getServerSession();
        Map sessionProp = ss.getProperties();

        if (tenantResolver != null && tenantResolver.getCurrentTenant() != null) {
            sessionProp.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT, tenantResolver.getCurrentTenant().getHandle());

            em = emf.createEntityManager(sessionProp);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("MultiTenantJpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction()-> Exception while creating EntityManagerForTransaction " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return em;
}
```

}

Currently testing with the above code it seem to have fixed the Issue.

Comment: The above code that I posted is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Following https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/multitenancy002.htm

this might work:

```
@Override
protected synchronized javax.persistence.EntityManager createEntityManagerForTransaction() {
    boolean refreshed = false;
    EntityManagerFactory emf = getEntityManagerFactory();
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        if (schemaProvider != null) {
            TenantSessionCustomizer.setSchemaName(schemaProvider.getSchema());
        }
        Map tenantProp = new HashMap();

        if (tenantResolver != null && tenantResolver.getCurrentTenant() != null) {
           tenantProp.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT, tenantResolver.getCurrentTenant().getHandle());

             em = emf.createEntityManager(tenantProp);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("MultiTenantJpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction()-> Exception while creating EntityManagerForTransaction " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return em;
}
```

Comment: In the line: if (tenantResolver != null && tenantResolver.getCurrentTenant() != null) {sessionProp.put(xxx) "sessionProp" did you mean it to have the statement line 1)ServerSession ss = ((EntityManagerImpl) em.getDelegate()).getServerSession(); line 2)  Map sessionProp = ss.getProperties(); in the earlier line (before if stmt)? because sessionProp in the method is not resolved. Please let me know

Comment: I think you ment tenantProp instead of sessionProp right?

Comment: Chris in the above code snippet you have provided the the map tenantProp is never set for the tenant-id property. Is it still meaning ful.

Comment: Cut and paste error from your method and the link.  sessionProp was meant to be tenantProp and I've corrected it.